# Why is my RegEx always returning 'true' in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

As part of a bash script I'm trying to build a filter that exits the script when an incorrect filename is passed:

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ [^DCS-932L20\d{14}(\.[jJ][pP][gG])$] ]]; then 
   echo "'$1' is not a valid name"
   exit 1
fi
```

When testing the RegEx in a debugger it matches the right string, for example: `DCS-932L2019110607132405.jpg`

But when implemented in the bash-script the IF-statement always returns `true`

When I shorten the RegEx to `[^DCS-]` everything seems to work, but adding just the '9' (`[^DCS-9]`) is enough to have the statement, again, always returning `true`

I tryed escaping (`[^DCS\-9]` or `[^DCS-\9]`)

I tryed quotes (`["^DCS-9"]` or `['^DCS-\9']`)

And I tryed combinations of those.

I'm a fairly newbee to both bash and RegEx, so if someone can explain what is wrong I wlold be thankfull

Comment: Why did you put the regex inside `[...]`? `\d` is not supported, BTW, use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: I copied this syntax with ```[...]``` from an other example.
Removing them, however does not seem to solve the problem.

Is the ```\d``` the problem ? I'll look into that !

Comment: Use `rx='^DCS-932L20[0-9]{14}\.[jJ][pP][gG]$'` and then `if [[ ! "$1" =~ $rx ]]; then ` See https://ideone.com/2mMQ6Z

Comment: ```rx='^DCS-932L20[0-9]{14}\.[jJ][pP][gG]$'``` works !!!
Thank you verry much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a bracket expression out of your regex by wrapping it with square brackets. Besides, Bash POSIX ERE regex does not support `\d` shorthand character class, you need to use either `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.

It is best to declare the regex before and use as an unquoted variable after `=~`:

```
rx='^DCS-932L20[0-9]{14}\.[jJ][pP][gG]$'
if [[ ! "$1" =~ $rx ]]; then
```

See an [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/2mMQ6Z).

Note you do not need the grouping parentheses here, hence they are removed.